# Laravel - accessing lang/en/validation.php from test suite

Tags: validation, laravel, testing

I want to test that warning messages are displayed correctly when form fields are returned as invalid. The best way to do this would be to access the array in validation.php to get the name of the language line that I want to use.

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? share your trials, please! We're not here to do the job for you

Comment: Apologies, I read the documentation though this escaped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Laravel is very great. You can access language files in `resources/lang/{locale}/` easily with the provided [`trans()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization#basic-usage) function (Laravel 5):

```
$expected = 'The :attribute may only contain letters.';
$actual = trans('validation.alpha');
$this->assertEquals($expected,$actual);
```

Please provide your attempts in the question next time. Also have a look at the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you will be rewarded with a bronze badge afterwards!)